# Flutter Drag and Drop Problems

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

in my application, I want to position the image in the toolbar wherever I want on the screen. I should be able to do this more than once, but my code is not suitable for this, I do not know where my mistake is, I can drag the picture on the screen as I want, I am having trouble getting it to drop, can you help?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:question_games/models/questions_model.dart';
import 'package:question_games/services/question_data.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;

  GameScreen({required this.value});

  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState(value: this.value);
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  int _currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  int _correctAnswers = 0;
  int _wrongAnswers = 0;
  final String value;
  List<bool> final_isImageDropped = List.filled(41, false, growable: false);
  List<Offset?> _points = <Offset?>[];
  bool _isDrawingMode = true;
  bool _isEraserMode = false;
  Offset _imagePosition = Offset(0, 0); // Resmin pozisyonunu tutacak değişken
  bool _isImagePlaced =
      false; // Resmin yerleştirilip yerleştirilmediğini kontrol eder

  _GameScreenState({required this.value});

  Future<void> _playSound(String fileName) async {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/$fileName'));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // İlk resim pozisyonunu ayarla
    _imagePosition = Offset(20, 20); // İlk başlangıç ??pozisyonu
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Question currentQuestion = questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Çizim ve Oyun Ekranı'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              currentQuestion.questionText,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                DragTarget<String>(
                  onWillAcceptWithDetails: (details) => true,
                  onAcceptWithDetails: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isImagePlaced = true;

                      // Burada resmin son konumunu ayarlayabilir ve gerekli işlemleri yapabilirsiniz
                    });
                  },
                  builder: (
                    BuildContext context,
                    List<dynamic> accepted,
                    List<dynamic> rejected,
                  ) {
                    return Container(
                      // Bu Container, DragTarget alanını temsil eder ve görünmez olabilir
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors
                            .transparent, // Arka plan rengi, görünmez olması için transparent olabilir
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onPanUpdate: (details) {
                          if (_isDrawingMode && !_isImagePlaced) {
                            setState(() {
                              RenderBox renderBox =
                                  context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                              Offset localPosition = renderBox
                                  .globalToLocal(details.localPosition);
                              _points.add(localPosition);
                            });
                          } else if (_isEraserMode) {
                            RenderBox renderBox =
                                context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                            Offset localPosition =
                                renderBox.globalToLocal(details.localPosition);
                            _updatePointsForErase(localPosition);
                          }
                        },
                        onPanEnd: (details) {
                          if (_isDrawingMode && !_isImagePlaced) {
                            _points.add(null);
                          }
                        },
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: MyPainter(points: _points),
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Draggable<String>(
                            data: currentQuestion.questionImageUrl2d,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 70,
                              height: 70,
                              child: Image.network(
                                  currentQuestion.questionImageUrl2d,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                            feedback: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              child: Image.network(
                                  currentQuestion.questionImageUrl2d,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                            childWhenDragging: Container(),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.brush),
                            onPressed: _enableDrawing,
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: _enableEraser,
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => _playSound('soundofApplause.mp3'),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.volume_up), // Alkış ikonu
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => _playSound('soundofDonk.mp3'),
                            icon: Icon(Icons
                                .music_note), // Donk sesi için müzik notu ikonu
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                if (_isImagePlaced)
                  Positioned(
                    left: _imagePosition.dx,
                    top: _imagePosition.dy,
                    child: Draggable(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Image.network(currentQuestion.questionImageUrl2d,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                      feedback: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Opacity(
                            opacity: 0.5,
                            child: Image.network(
                                currentQuestion.questionImageUrl2d,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      ),
                      onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
                        setState(() {
                          _imagePosition = offset;
                        });
                      },
                      onDragUpdate: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          _imagePosition = details.globalPosition -
                              Offset(50,
                                  50); // Resmin sürükleme işlemi sırasında konumunu güncelle
                        });
                      },
                      childWhenDragging: Container(),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
         
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `Draggable`s. First when you move the image from toolbar and the second one when you placed the image in the target.

The second one updates the image position but the first one doesn't.

You can update the image using `onDragUpdate`, `onDragEnd` or other methods for `Draggable`, (like you did for the second `Draggable`), Or you can update it in `onAcceptWithDetails` like this:

```
onAcceptWithDetails: (details) {
 _imagePosition = details.offset;
 setState(() {
  _isImagePlaced = true;
 });
},
```